# Track if any friend has changed his/her profile picture graph api or fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

In regards to facebook Graph API or FQL, Is there a straight forward way of finding the info of friend(s) who have made changes in their profile picture in the past couple of days or have updated profile picture to something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fairly easily find friends who added a new profile picture using FQL, since new profile pictures end up in a standardized album.

This query will get you the ID of all friends who have added new profile pictures in the last week:

```
SELECT owner, object_id, modified_major FROM album 
 WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
       AND type = "profile" AND modified_major > strtotime("-1 week") 
 ORDER BY modified_major DESC
```

Of course, it won't show you friends who reverted to an old profile picture.

Checking changes requires querying the `stream` table (and dealing with its limitations) and looking for a specific string in a `story` thread.

This would deal with friends who changed their profile picture back to one that already existed in their 'profile' album, but I don't get a full week's worth of results.

```
SELECT updated_time, source_id, description FROM stream 
  WHERE filter_key = "others" AND strpos(description, "profile") > 0 
        AND updated_time > strtotime("-1 week") 
  LIMIT 500
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about your section solution as well, checking for "Profile Pictures" string in the story and then filtering data on the basis of same. Thanks for the help though.. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Nope**

No way of doing this through Facebook's API. You'd have to setup a cron job of sorts to periodically request the data and make comparisons with previous data.

Keep in mind that you would need extended access tokens in order to request data from a user that is not currently connected to your application.

Comment: Yeah, That's what I thought of, Apparently I was looking for a shortcut ;)